# Problems with populating database

Tags: php, sql

Good Afternoon,

Within one of my functions closing an account I am trying to populate a close account table:

```
mysqli_query($this->conn,"INSERT INTO marshalAccountCloses (`userID`, `firstName`, 'timestamp', reason)
        VALUES ($userID,$firstName,$currentDate,$reason)") 
        or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));
```

But I get the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''timestamp', reason) VALUES (42,Jamie,2024-03-20-02:03:25,Enter reason here)' at line 1

I have tried removing and adding the quote marks but no joy.

Comment: Pay closer attention to the basics of your code. You have (correctly) backticks round the first two column names and then (apparently randomly) quote marks round the 3rd, and none round the 4th. None isn't a problem if the column name contains no spaces etc, but the quote marks _are_ an issue.

Comment: Secondly, not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their name (such as `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`. Or in your case, the complete lack of any quoting round the $firstName variable would crash it anyway, because SQL won't even see it as a string!

Comment: But instead you *must* use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Comment: It looks like maybe you've a) been following some really old, obsolete, poor-quality tutorial and b) compounding that by not paying close attention to detail. When you write code, every single character you type is significant.

Comment: I have now tired this but am getting further errorsmysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO marshalAccountCloses (userID, firstName, timestamp, reason) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("isss", $userID , $firstName, $timestamp, $reason);

$userID = $userID;
$firstName = $firstName;
$timestamp = $timestamp;
$reason = $reason;
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

Comment: What errors exactly? We can't help you with errors if you don't mention them!

Comment: P.s. you need to put mysqli_report _before_ you first connect to the database, as I described

Comment: ADyson thank you for your help, I was struggling to find the error but placing the error handing in the right place helped me find it. Am new to this so grateful for your help